# Springboot 1.5.7 with mongodb driver 3.8.2

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

My project is currently working with an elder spring boot version 1.5.7 and we wanna use a mongodb 4.0

Due to the gap between spring boot versions 1.5 to 2.X, i would like to upgrade for now the mongodb driver only by using a 3.8.2

My need is only some records and fetchs, any ACID specifics needs sure as update a doc with several processes

I tried locally and i got any errors,

My question is although it's not the best way, is there any fallback by doing that?

(Notes: I will upgrade my spring boot version later)

Thank by advance

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is an opinionated framework and also has opinions about the used dependency versions.

So it's never a good idea to upgrade the dependency versions without upgrading Spring Boot itself.

I would not recommend to upgrade just the Mongo DB driver.

Comment: Absolutely true, mongo upgrades are designed taking spring boot version into consideration. So it always a good practice to choose the driver version that spring boot can support it.